# is it possible to distruct two values from async/await [any solution]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

so i have been playing around with promises in different ways here i was trying to understand how to implement both promises and async/await in different ways and i'v encountered difficulties what i'm trying to do is to transfering this piece of code(the one that works) into this async/await, and it was messy and it did not work for me
[pardon my english and my code writing]

**Works Perfectly**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!pokemonName) {
      return
    }
    setPokemon(null);
    setError(null)
    fetchPokemon(pokemonName).then(
      pokemon => setPokemon(pokemon),
      error => setError(error),
    )
  }, [pokemonName])
```

**Did not work**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
            if (!pokemonName) {
              return
            }
            setPokemon(null)
            setError(null)
            async function effect() {
              const [result,error] = await fetchPokemon(pokemonName);
              if(error){
                return setError(error);
              }else{
                return setPokemon(result);
              }
            }
            effect()
          }, [pokemonName])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the first snippet to

```
React.useEffect(async () => {
    if (!pokemonName) {
      return
    }
    setPokemon(null);
    setError(null)
    try {
      setPokemon(await fetchPokemon(pokemonName));
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    }
  }, [pokemonName])
```

An asynchronous function call with `await` doesn't return an error. It throws the error. Therefore you have to catch potential errors. If the function can't be `async` you can use a immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!pokemonName) {
      return
    }
    setPokemon(null);
    setError(null)
    (async () => {
      try {
        setPokemon(await fetchPokemon(pokemonName));
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [pokemonName])
```

Comment: it worked like charm just keep in mind  about the useEffect(React.useEffect(async () => .......) hook is that you cannot  return anything other than the cleanup function. in this case you are returning a promise due to the semantics of async/await syntax , But the second worked so fine and i'v learned a lot thank you